# Color features extraction through clustering in image searching engine

Tags: algorithm, search, image-processing, colors, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to implement a perceptual-based image searching engine, that will allow users to find pictures, containing objects of relatively same or close colours to the user-specified template(object from the sample image).

The goal for now is not to match a precise object, but rather to find any significant areas that are close in color to the template. I am stuck with indexing my dataset.

I have tried some clustering algorithms, such as k-means from sklearn.cluster (as I've read from [this article](http://cvgl.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231a_winter1415/prev/projects/CS231AFinalProjectReport.pdf)), to select centroids from the sample image as my features, that are eventually in CIELab color space to acquire more perceptual uniformity. But it doesn't seem to work well, as cluster centres are generated randomly and thus I've got poor metrics results even on an object and image, from which that same object was extracted!

As far as I'm concerned, a common algorithm in simple image searching programs is using distance between histograms, which is not acceptable as I try to sustain perceptually-valid colour difference, and by that I mean that I can only manage two separate colours (and maybe some additional values) to calculate [metrics in CIELab colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference). I am using CMCl:c metric of my own implementation, and it produced good results so far.

Maybe someone can help me and recommend an algorithm more suitable for my purpose.

Some code that I've done so far:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans
from imageproc.color_metrics import *

def feature_extraction(image, features_length=6):
    width, height, dimensions = tuple(image.shape)

    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    image = cv.medianBlur(image, 7)

    image = np.reshape(image, (width * height, dimensions))

    clustering_handler = MiniBatchKMeans(n_init=40, tol=0.0, n_clusters=features_length, compute_labels=False,
                                     max_no_improvement=10, max_iter=200, reassignment_ratio=0.01)
clustering_handler.fit(image)

    features = np.array(clustering_handler.cluster_centers_, dtype=np.float64)
    features[:, :1] /= 255.0
    features[:, :1] *= 100.0
    features[:, 1:2] -= 128.0
    features[:, 2:3] -= 128.0

    return features

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_image_name = object_image_name
    second_image_name = image_name

    sample_features = list()
    reference_features = list()

    for name, features in zip([first_image_name, second_image_name], [sample_features, reference_features]):
        image = cv.imread(name)
        features.extend(feature_extraction(image, 6))
    distance_matrix = np.ndarray((6, 6))
    distance_mappings = {}

    for n, i in enumerate(sample_features):
        for k, j in enumerate(reference_features):
            distance_matrix[n][k] = calculate_cmc_distance(i, j)
            distance_mappings.update({distance_matrix[n][k]: (i, j)})



    minimal_distances = []
    for i in distance_matrix:
        minimal_distances.append(min(i))

    minimal_distances = sorted(minimal_distances)
    print(minimal_distances)
    for ii in minimal_distances:
        i, j = distance_mappings[ii]
        color_plate1 = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.float32)
        color_plate2 = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.float32)

        color1 = cv.cvtColor(np.float32([[i]]), cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)[0][0]
        color2 = cv.cvtColor(np.float32([[j]]), cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)[0][0]

        color_plate1[:] = color1
        color_plate2[:] = color2

        cv.imshow("s", np.hstack((color_plate1, color_plate2)))
        cv.waitKey()

    print(sum(minimal_distances))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach would be to cluster only *once*, with a representative sample from *all* images.

This is a preprocessing step, to generate your "dictionary".

Then for feature extraction, you would map points to the *fixed* cluster centers, that are now **shared across all images**. This is a simple nearest-neighbor mapping, no clustering.